# How do I generate a SOAP-compatible XML response with correct namespace prefixes?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I'm writing a small web server (HttpListener) which will ultimately run as part of a Windows service and response to SOAP requests from another application.

I've written the code to decode the SOAP request XML and extract the action, process it and get the result, but can't quite get the response XML to be generated correctly.

I've like to avoid generating each element individually since the Types of the response may vary and I don't want to have to code every variant into the web server and would prefer not to have to delve into Reflection and walk the Type structure to output the values. I'd prefer to use something simple like the XmlSerializer Serialize method (which presumably is walking the Type structure), but it's not clear if it has enough control.

The output I'm trying to produce in my test program is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetUsernamesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetUsernamesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApp2"
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Results xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
          <b:string>Kermit.The.Frog</b:string>
          <b:string>Miss.Piggy</b:string>
        </a:Results>
      </GetUsernamesResult>
    </GetUsernamesResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetUsernamesResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetUsernamesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApp2" 
                xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" 
                xmlns="">
        <Results>
          <string>Kermit.The.Frog</string>
          <string>Miss.Piggy</string>
        </Results>
      </GetUsernamesResult>
    </GetUsernamesResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is the current test program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class GetUsernamesResponse
    {
        public List<string> Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetUsernamesResult : GetUsernamesResponse {}

    public class Program
    {
        private const string ns_t = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private const string ns_s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        private const string ns_i = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        private const string ns_a = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApp2";
        private const string ns_b = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var r = new GetUsernamesResult()
            {
                Results = new List<string>
                {
                    "Kermit.The.Frog",
                    "Miss.Piggy"
                }
            };

            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("i", ns_i);
            ns.Add("a", ns_a);
            ns.Add("b", ns_b);

            var oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetUsernamesResult));
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var xw = XmlWriter.Create(
                    sw,
                    new XmlWriterSettings()
                    {
                        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                        Indent = true,
                        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
                        NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
                    });
                xw.WriteStartElement("s", "Envelope", ns_s);
                xw.WriteStartElement("s", "Body", ns_s);
                xw.WriteStartElement($"GetUsernamesResponse", ns_t);
                xw.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "i", null, ns_i);
                oSerializer.Serialize(xw, r, ns);
                xw.WriteEndElement();
                xw.WriteEndElement();
                xw.WriteEndElement();
                xw.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(sw);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done with Serialize or do have to do it with Reflection and, effectively, reproduce what the SOAP responder in IIS is already doing?

FYI, I also tried setting up a Type mapping...

```
var mapping = new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof(BarcodeProductionGetUsernamesResult));
var oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(mapping);
```

... but the resultant XML was totally different and, although it didn't produce an error, also didn't decode in the calling application; a null value was returned

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetUsernamesResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetUsernamesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApp2" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" id="id1" xmlns="">
      <Results href="#id2" />
    </GetUsernamesResult>
    <q1:Array id="id2" xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" q1:arrayType="q2:string[2]" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <Item xmlns="">Kermit.The.Frog</Item>
        <Item xmlns="">Miss.Piggy</Item>
      </q1:Array>
    </GetUsernamesResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: You are not writing any element with ns_a nor ns_b which is why none of the output contains a: or b:.

Comment: I realise that and am coming to the conclusion that, unless the object/class is already decorated with XmlElement attributes, the only solution is to actually walk the structure with Reflection and generate the elements explicitly. It appears there's no automatic mechanism to recognised arrays/lists/collections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use xml linq.  For complicated headers a namespaces I just parse a string to get desired results.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

            XDocument doc = MySerializer<MyClass>.GetXElement(myClass);
        }
    }

    public class MySerializer<T> where T : new()
    {
        static string xml =
           "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
           "    <s:Body>" +
           "       <GetUsernamesResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
           "          <GetUsernamesResult xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApp2\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
           "             <a:Results xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">" +
           "             </a:Results>" +
           "          </GetUsernamesResult>" +
           "      </GetUsernamesResponse>" +
           "   </s:Body>" +
           "</s:Envelope>";
        public static XDocument GetXElement(T myClass)
        {


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Results").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns_b = results.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("b");

            StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sWriter);

            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns1 = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns1.Add("b", ns_b.NamespaceName);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), ns_b.NamespaceName);
            serializer.Serialize(xWriter, myClass, ns1);
            results.Add(XElement.Parse(sWriter.ToString()));

            return doc;
        }

    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is specific to the class/Type, since you've included the XML which needs to be generated. The actual application, as I mentioned, may use several different Types [in fact, the call is `var oXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(responseType)`] so I don't have the specific structure and was hoping to avoid having a section for each different type; after all, the SOAP responder in IIS does this for any Type it sees. I think I am going to have to delve into Reflection and re-invent the 'wheel' which must exist in IIS. :)

Comment: I would think the response header(s) would be the same and only the results would be different.  You can wrap the xml results from the unique actions in my code.

Comment: Adding the response headers isn't a problem. The issue I'm having is how to walk the class structure (which could be any one of over a dozen classes). The key statements in the 'real' program are `var method = typeof(IMyService).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.Equals(action)).First();` then `var methResult = method.ReturnType;` and later `var xResult = Convert.ChangeType(method.Invoke(_myService, new object[] { requestObj })),methResult);`.So when the final XML is being generated, all that's known is that `xResult` has the Type contained in `methResult`, but it could be almost anything